# Number of changes it takes to turn a string to another

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the number of changes it takes to change
the first string, s1 to s2. I wrote a function to do exactly this
but the problem with what I have so far is that if the first two characters
are different then it would return 1 and not look at the rest of the string.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def num_of_changes(s1, s2):
    if not s1:
        return len(s2)
    if not s2:
        return len(s1)
    length = 0
    # if the first char in both the string are the same, then call the function
    # again on the rest of the string after the first char.
    # so if s1 = cat and s2 = cbt since the first char on both strings is
    # the same it call the function again on the rest, the rest in this case
    # being s1 = at and s2 = bt
    if s1[0] == s2[0]:
        num_of_changes(s1[length+1:], s2[length+1:])
    # if the first characters on both the strings aren't the same, then
    # increase the length by 1, and call the function again on the rest of the
    # string after length + 1.
    # so if s1 = cat and s2 = bat, since the first char from both the strings
    # arent the same it calls the function on length+1. Since the length
    # increased to 1 becase the first char isn't the same, the it would be
    # length=1, so 1+1
    # Therefore, it would call the function on s1 = at and s2 = at
    else:
        length += 1
        num_of_changes(s1[length+1:], s2[length+1:])
    # returns the number stored in the length variable.
    return length
```

Comment: your recursive function has to take length as a param, so you could pass it on every recursive call.

Comment: The name for this is [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value from the recursive calls. They return a length, but those values are dropped on the floor. If we remove these recursive calls, then, your code is equivalent to:

```
length = 0
if s1[0] == s2[0]:
    pass
else:
    length += 1
return length
```

As you can see, it will only return 0 or 1.

You need to get the recursive values and then conditionally add 1 if the first characters are a match.

```
if s1[0] == s2[0]:
    return num_of_changes(s1[length+1:], s2[length+1:])
else:
    return num_of_changes(s1[length+1:], s2[length+1:]) + 1
```

By changing `length+1` to `1`, and merging the two return statements, this could then be simplified to:

```
return num_of_changes(s1[1:], s2[1:]) + (1 if s1[0] == s2[0] else 0)
```

It may be a bit dense, but this makes it very clear what you're returning: it's the value from the recursive call, plus 1 if `s1[0] == s2[0]`.

Comment: You can also remove `length`:
`num_of_changes(s1[1:], s2[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is known as edit distance, or Levenshtein distance, between two strings. You can find it implemented for you on the python-Levenshtein package. Install it via:

```
$ sudo pip install python-Levenshtein
```

And use it like this:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.distance('abba', 'baba')
2
```